# How To test a web page using Facebook SDK JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I implemented facebook SDK JavaScript in my web page for login but i can't test my app, I'm using sublimetext 2 for developing my web page, I know the answer for my problem this is implement a web service, but I don't know the best form to implement this service or the best solution for test facebook SDK JavaScript.

For a clear idea this is my code:

**index.html**
    ...

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '364802373701256',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        alert('Logged in.');
      }
      else {
        FB.login();
      }
    });

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">

        <button  id="facebookLogin" class="btn btn-primary bt-social form-control" data-provider="facebook">Facebook</button>
        <button href="#" class="btn btn-danger bt-social form-control" data-provider="google">Google+</butt
      </form>                 
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
...
```

**facebookLogin.js**

```
$("#acebookLogin").click(function(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
});

function statusChangeCallback(response){
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        if(response.status === 'connected'){
            console.log('isConnected');
}
else{
    if(response.status === 'not_authorized'){
        console.log(' The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app');
    }
    else{
        console.log('The person is not logged into Facebook, so we re not sure if they are logged into this app or not');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you mean you are running this from your local filesystem then you need to change the facebook library url to use an actual protocol, otherwise it will try to use `file:///`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I don't know to you refer when you mention change the facebook library url to use an actual protocol if you could help me expanding your answer really It would be helpful.

Comment: `"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"` needs to be `"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved this problem adding the local URL for my app (example: http://localhost:8000/login.html) into setting for my app in Developer Facebook site.